# 意図しないuserのidを取得しています…

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### 前提・実現したいこと

indexページ(ホーム)でログインしているユーザーのidを取得したいです。
id取得後、ログインしているユーザーが登録した画像アイコンを取り出します。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

【page_controller.rb】

```
def index
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
end
```

【application.html.erb】

```
   ・
   ・
<body>
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  </div> 
   ・
   ・
```

【_header.html.erb】

```
  ・
  ・
 <li>
  <%= link_to current_user do %>
   <%= render 'layouts/header_image' %>
   <%= current_user.username %>
  <% end %>
 </li>
  ・
  ・
```

【_header_image.html.erb】

```
  ・
  ・
 <% if !@user.image.url.nil? %>
  <%= image_tag(@user.image.url, :alt => "アイコン", :width => '40', :height => '30', class: "header-icon") %>
 <% else %>
  <%= image_tag("no-image.png", :alt => "アイコン", :width => '40', :height => '30', class: "header-icon") %>
 <% end %>
  ・
  ・
```

ここで、取り出してほしい画像はUser.idが3のユーザーの画像です。
しかし、実際に取り出されるのはUser.idが1のユーザーになってしまいます…

#### 補足情報

①User.idは1も3も存在しており、どちらも画像をpublicから取り出しています。
②Carrierwaveを使っています。
③User#showでも同様に画像を取り出していますが、こちらは意図した画像を取り出してくれます。

【**User#show**】

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**index#page**では
*@user = User.find(params[:id])*でデータを取り出せないので、
**@user = User.find_by(params[:id])**を使っています。

何卒よろしくお願いします。

マルチポスト
[テラテイル](https://teratail.com/questions/56722?modal=q-comp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 「ログインしているユーザー」の id はどうやって取得しているのですか?
- 検索に使っている `params[:id]` にはちゃんと値が入っていますか? もしかして `nil` や `""` (空文字列) ではありませんか?
- `#index` へのアクセスの時のURL(`?` の後ろがあるならそれも含めて)はどういったものですか?

Comment: sakuroさん

できました！
原因は、ログインしているユーザーのidを取得していなかったことでした。
そこで、

#indexで@user = User.find_by(id: current_user.id)を設定したところ意図した画像を取り出すことができました！

sakuroさんのご指摘を一つ一つ試していったところクリアできました。ありがとうございます！